# Issue regarding component Responsive Scroll Triggered Box

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I have installed a component called 'Responsive Scroll Triggered Box', but when I activate the component, it gives Javascript errors, and makes the sideshow crash because of it.
This is the component `script.js` file

```
/**
 * @package         Responsive Scroll Triggered Box
 * @author          Tassos Marinos <info@tassos.gr>
 * @link            http://www.tassos.gr
 * @copyright       Copyright © 2015 TM Extensions All Rights Reserved
 * @license         http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 */

var jqRSTBox = jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* Joomla <= 3.3.6 - Added change trigger when check the radio input */
        $('.btn-group label:not(.active)').click(function() {
            var input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
            if (!input.prop('checked')) {
                input.trigger('change');
            }
        });

        /* Trigger Method */
        $("#jform_triggermethod").change(function() {
            val = $(this).val();
            switch (val) {
                case "pageheight":
                    disableObjects = ["prmtriggerelement"];
                    break;
                case "pageload":
                    disableObjects = ["prmtriggerelement", "prmtriggerpercentage","prmautohide"];
                    break;
                case "userleave":
                    disableObjects = ["prmtriggerelement", "prmtriggerpercentage","prmtriggerdelay","prmautohide"];
                    break;
                case "element":
                    disableObjects = ["prmtriggerpercentage"];
                    break;
            }

            form = $(this).closest("form#adminForm");

            form.find(".control-group").removeClass("hide");
            disableObjects.each(function(x) {
                form.find(".control-group."+x).addClass("hide");
            })
        }).trigger('change');

        /* Show/Hide Fieldsets */
        showOnFields = [
            {
                "trigger": $('select#jform_boxtype'),
                "triggerValues": ["module"],
                "showField" : $("#module")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('select#jform_boxtype'),
                "triggerValues": ["custom"],
                "showField" : $("#custom")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('select#jform_boxtype'),
                "triggerValues": ["emailform"],
                "showField" : $("#emailform")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('input[name="jform[prm_assign_devices]"]'),
                "triggerValues": ["1","2"],
                "showField" : $(".prmassigndeviceslist")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('input[name="jform[prm_overlay]"]'),
                "triggerValues" : ["1"],
                "showField": $(".prmoverlaycolor, .prmoverlaypercent, .prmoverlayclick")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('input[name="jform[prm_allmenus]"]'),
                "triggerValues" : ["0"],
                "showField": $(".menuitems")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('input[name="jform[prm_assign_lang]"]'),
                "triggerValues": ["1","2"],
                "showField": $(".prmassignlanglist")
            },
            {
                "trigger": $('select[name="jform[prm_cookietype]"]'),
                "triggerValues": ["seconds","minutes", "days", "hours"],
                "showField": $(".cookie")
            }
        ]

        $.each(showOnFields, function(key, value) {
            trigger = $(value.trigger);
            trigger.on("change", function() {

                valid = false;

                if (value.triggerValues == ":checked") {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                }

                if ($.isArray(value.triggerValues)) {
                    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), value.triggerValues) > -1) {
                        valid = true;
                    }   
                }  

                if (valid) {
                    value.showField.slideDown("fast");
                } else {
                    value.showField.slideUp("fast");
                }
            });

            if (trigger.is("select")) {
                trigger.trigger("change");
            }

            if (trigger.is("input:radio")) {
                trigger.filter(":checked").trigger("change"); 
            }
        });
    });
}(jqRSTBox));
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what these JS errors are?

Comment: JS errors mean that there is a conflict between $ and jQuery. but the problem is solved. i just need to add a joomla plugin jquery-easy which removes the conflicts between the mootools and jquery

Comment: Please write this as an answer below and mark is as accepted to people know it has been solved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. I just need to add a joomla plugin jquery-easy which removes the conflicts between the mootools and jquery

Answer (score 0):

I see this has been answered as a Mootools / JQuery conflict.  It is worth noting that Mootools has been deprecated in Joomla 3, though I believe is still sometimes used in the admin.

The fact your site has Mootools and JQuery suggests that your template (or possibly some other extension) may be getting out-of-date, or your site unpatched if you are using a core template.

Up-to-date Joomla sites should be using JQuery only - it is probably worth looking into where and why Mootools is still being used.

For more details: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks